# Вопрос по ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

прочитав мануалы и не нашел для себя решения я решил обратится сюда.

Создается объект m там только одно поле типа String name.

```
Media m  = new Media("first");
Library lib = new Library();
lib.store(m);
lib.retreiveByName("first");

lib.store(m); // занесение объекта в список лист ниже реализация метода.
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();

@Override
public <T> void store(T media) {
    list.add(media);
}
```

Вопрос как по полю name найти в списке эл. пробую реализовать так :

```
@Override
public void retreiveByName(String name) {
    System.out.println(list.indexOf(name));
}
```

Но так не находит, как правильно это реализовать ?

Comment: hashmap попробуй

Comment: в задании сказано" В качестве хранилища элементов в классе Library<T> использовать ArrayList "

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нужно в цикле перебрать все объекты в списке. У каждого сравнивать поле name с аргументом и в случае успеха - возвращать этот объект.

```
List<Media> list = new ArrayList<Media>();

public Media retreiveByName(String name) {
    for (Media m: list) {
        if (name.equals(m.getName())) {
            return m;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Еще лучше для этой задачи подойдет коллекция HashMap. Она позволяет удобно и быстро находить значение по ключу. В качестве ключа в вашем случае будет название, а в качестве значения - сам объект.

```
Map<Media> map = new HashMap<Media>();

public void store(Media media) {
    map.put(media.getName(), media);
}

public Media retreiveByName(String name) {
    return map.get(name);   
}
```